# How to have a touches began and tap gesture on a button?

Tags: ios, swift

I've got buttons that I'm creating programmatically on the screen.

When I give them a touchesBegan/touchesMoved etc in their custom class, my action to click it is never called and the touchesBegan is overriding it I guess.

I need separate functionality for when the user touches and drags the button and if they just tap it, but I'm not seeing how to maintain the button's action that I'm giving it on creation because of the touches being given higher priority I guess.

How would this be accomplished?

Comment: UIButton class already has this functionality built in.   There are recognition for touching a button for touchUpInside/touchDown and touchDragOutside

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog Maybe I'm not understanding. Up until the point I assigned the button I'm creating programmatically a class that has touches began/moved/ended functions, the built in functionality of detecting touches inside worked, but once the buttons are draggable, when the user touches the button, touchesBegan is called and the touchUpInside action is no longer called. 

Is it possible to differentiate between tapping a button and touchesStarted/Touches ending on it? Maybe not now that I think about it

Comment: when touchesBegan is called, it gives you a location in the screen where the touch happened.  If that touch is located within the frame of the button then you should perform the action for tapping a button.